# How to pass a variable to Ruby through Ajax?

Tags: ruby, ajax

I have this code and it won't work unless I pass a constant to **data**. What am I doing wrong?

```
function onMapClick(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/temps",
    type: "POST",
    data: {coordinates: e.latlng},
    success: function(response) {
      // map.openPopup("hello", e.latlon);
      alert(e.latlng.lat);
      // return response;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking here, really?

Comment: It sounds like e.latlng doesn't exist.  What happens when you console.log(e.latlng) before doing the $.ajax()?

Comment: No, it exists, because when I put data: 123, then this alert(e.latlng.lat) gives some coordinates, so I know it exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [toJSON](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp) to turn the data into a json string, then when you receive it in your ruby code you can use [JSON.parse(data)](http://flori.github.io/json/)